# Creating a Board Presentation for Chess Game

Tags: java, arrays, chess

I am starting to make a 8 x 8 square board for Chess Game Assignment. However, I am wondering if there's anything hint to create the square rather than the 2D array in Java.

one of the restrictions for the assignment disallows to use 2D array or any similar. There's no AI but user control only.

Comment: You could use a 1D array if that is not too similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use one-dimensional array, say `Figure [] board = new Figure[64]` and make a simple getter/setter method to emulate 2-dimensions:

```
Figure get(int hor, int vert) {
  return board[hor*8+ver];
}

void set(int hor, int vert, Figure f) {
  board[hor*8+ver] = f;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a 1 dimensional array or `ArrayList` and then divide by 8 and use the result and the remainder to know in which column and row you need to go.

You can then work the other way round to obtain the location in the array for the corresponding chess board section.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use Map:

```
private Map<String, Figure> board = new HashMap<String, Figure>();

private String positionToString(int hor, int vert) {
    return hor + " " + vert;
}

public Figure get(int hor, int vert) {
    return board.get(positionToString(hor, vert));
}

public void set(int hor, int vert, Figure fig) {
    board.put(positionToString(hor, vert), fig);
}
```

Comment: Map and string<->int conversion here is unnessesary. It will only lead to performance losses.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov: so? try a `std::pair<int,int>`?

Comment: And it is easy to switch to board of any dimension without changing code, if we use Map :)

Comment: Don't know the context of problem, but if e.g. we will count all possible positions in chess tree (maybe solving chess problem or writing AI), I can guarantee you that your code will work 3 times slower at least than naive 2d-array board representation.

Comment: @sehe java doesn't have std::pair

Comment: It's easy to switch to any dimension if we use variables (or constant) instead of '8'

Comment: @korifey, yes, if we need really high performance then my implementation is not very good.

Comment: @korifey but you need to specify somewhere variable it or even change code and recompile if we use constant. So it has some advantages.

Answer (score 2):

I have no working knowledge of Java, I play chess and do some Delphi programming. I have no idea of bit manipulation capabilities of Java.

But, I suggest you to investigate on [Bitboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) data structure and search on the net for open source chess engine based on it.

It's a commonplace in c++ world.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps yo ucan get away with not even creating a square in the first place?

An alternate way to represent a chess board would be just a list of pieces and their respective coordinates.